# What is the difference print a object directly and print a object after call str function in python

Tags: python, unicode

First I create a unicode object like;

```
test = u'\u015f\xfckr\xfc\xe7a\u011fl\xfcli'
```

When I print this object;

```
>>> print test
şükrüçağlüli
```

However when I run this command, I get a UnicodeEncodeError;

```
>>> print str(test)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Why this error is rised? Print call str function, doesn't it?

Comment: Unicode primer: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Print call str function, doesn't it?

No, not for Unicode strings, it doesn't. For Unicode strings, `print` leaves them as is and leaves encoding the value to the `sys.stdout` object; this object will encode Unicode values to the encoding used by your terminal or console.

`str()` on a Unicode value implicitly encodes it to ASCII. If you have to convert Unicode values to a byte string, encode explicitly:

```
print test.encode('utf-8')
```

would write UTF-8 bytes to your terminal.

Writing to `sys.stdout` does the exact same thing, but uses `sys.stdout.encoding` for this rather than hard-code an encoding. `sys.stdout.encoding` reflects what encoding Python detected for your terminal or console.

See [`file.encoding`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.encoding):

> The encoding that this file uses. When Unicode strings are written to a file, they will be converted to byte strings using this encoding. In addition, when the file is connected to a terminal, the attribute gives the encoding that the terminal is likely to use (that information might be incorrect if the user has misconfigured the terminal). The attribute is read-only and may not be present on all file-like objects. It may also be None, in which case the file uses the system default encoding for converting Unicode strings.

`file.encoding` is only ever set for `sys.std*` file objects and you cannot set the attribute from Python code.

Comment: Is this behavior relevant both for Python 2 & 3 ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: updated; the encoding is actually taken care of by file objects; this applies to both Python 2 and 3.